# Multiple Line in one Cell with the same record

Tags: jquery, database

I want to show in one the column in my DataTables,  records which my have until 300 chars. But it's not possible because the column will take one large space in the table.

I would like that, when the number of chars arrive 100, there was one break line for the print of chars 101 until 200 in one second line and the same for 3ª line

I put so:

```
"columns":[ { "data": "name", "width": "70px",} ]
```

but the column make one auto-tuning, not respecting the fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, in my html code I put the css class *nowrap* int tag . This class force the Datatables the to show the content of one record in only line.
I removed this class and it worked.